# XML Serializing list of elements with base type

Tags: .net, xml, serialization

In .Net I have a number of classes with base class needed to be serialized to XML.

```
class Action {}
class AddCircle : Action
class DeleteCircle : Action
class AddTriangle : Action
class DeleteTriangle : Action
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>
{
new AddCircle(), 
new AddCircle(), 
new AddTriangle(), 
new DeleteTriangle(), 
new DeleteCircle(),
new AddTriangle()
}
```

And I need to serialize it to XML like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Actions>
  <CircleActions>
    <AddCircle />
    <AddCircle />
  </CircleActions>
  <TriangleActions>
    <AddTriangle />
    <DeleteTriangle />
  </TriangleActions>
  <CircleActions>
    <DeleteCircle />
  </CircleActions>
  <TriangleActions>
    <AddTriangle />
  </TriangleActions>
</Actions>
```

Is this possible to do using XmlSerializer?

Comment: No.  The Xml would need to have 'type' attributes corresponding to the inherited class names.  The best way of seeing what would happen is to serialize sample data.

Comment: Actually, it is possible by adding grouping classes, in this example CircleActions, TriangleActions, etc, Actions would be List<BaseGroup>, and BaseGrou has List<Action>
Also it is necessary to implement a code which adds starting group, and when adding Action to Actions, add new if last one (current) is not of the same type.

Comment: Did you look at the xml I posted in my answer?

Comment: Yes, and your answer doesn't have groups

Comment: Action is a base class in your code and the inherited classes will not work without the type attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I serialized the data so you can see results

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Root root = new Root()
            {
                actions = new List<Action>() {
                    new AddCircle(),
                    new AddCircle(),
                    new AddTriangle(),
                    new DeleteTriangle(),
                    new DeleteCircle(),
                    new AddTriangle()
                 }
            };

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, root);
        }
    }
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Action")]
        public List<Action> actions { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlInclude(typeof(AddCircle))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(DeleteCircle))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(AddTriangle))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(DeleteTriangle))]
    public class Action { }
    public class AddCircle : Action { }
    public class DeleteCircle : Action { }
    public class AddTriangle : Action { }
    public class DeleteTriangle : Action { }
}
```

Here is the Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Action xsi:type="AddCircle" />
  <Action xsi:type="AddCircle" />
  <Action xsi:type="AddTriangle" />
  <Action xsi:type="DeleteTriangle" />
  <Action xsi:type="DeleteCircle" />
  <Action xsi:type="AddTriangle" />
</Root>
```